# How to get the pricing list of Google Compute Engine using API

Tags: java, google-compute-engine

Is there any way to retrieve the pricing list of Google Compute Engine using java API? Or at least the cost of a specific MachineType?

Answer (score 0):

There is not an API to currently provide that information.